# Question about eigen values of a compact operator on a Hilbert Space

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $T:H\rightarrow H$ be a compact operator. We know that if $\lambda\neq 0$ is an eigen value of of $T$, then the eigen space of $\lambda$ is finite dimensional. Can we say the same when $\lambda=0$, ie is it true that the dimension of the null space of $T$ is finite  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely not.  For example, the $0$ operator is compact and has null space all of $H$.